# Setting a question font / style that will apply to text and inline math environment?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, macros

I have defined two commands for the font/style of questions and key concepts in my notes as follows:

```
\newcommand{\key}[1]{{\bfseries\sffamily#1}}
\newcommand{\qtxt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

Where the commands can be altered at any time to change the appearance of these parts throughout the document (in case anyone is wondering why I wouldn't simply use `\textbf{}` itself).

However, whenever math symbols are included in either of these, I have to wrap them in `\boldsymbol{ }` (or equivalent) to get the desired (consistent) effect. Is there any way that I can define the above commands so that they will apply one rule to text and another rule to anything in `$ $` environment?

Comment: there's a `\boldmath` command (switch) in the latex core.  i'm not sure whether it copes with absolutely everything, but it's probably worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\qtxt}[1]{\textbf{\boldmath#1}}
```

should do bold. Sans serif is trickier as it depends what you want, typically there won't be a "sans serif math italic" (whatever that would mean) to use as the default math symbol font.

Comment: Thank you for your time & solution. I can't believe it was that simple. Any suggestions on where to learn more about how this works? I would've thought that would render everything in a math environment - I'd like to understand how it is working / learn about how it implements.

Comment: @RaxAdaam `\boldmath` should be mentioned in any latex tutorial, it is a declaration that says any math in its scope should be set using the bold mathversion. It doesn't, itself, start math mode.